# how to turn on dnssec on ubuntu 20.04 as client via systemd-resolved

Tags: 20.04, dns, systemd-resolved

I want to turn on dnssec validation on ubuntu 20.04 as a normal client. When I do `dig +dnssec` on my router as name server it returns a rrsig. I assume that this means, that the router is capable of dnssec validation. I also added some dnssec validating dns servers to resolved.conf. But when I use the systemd-resolved nameserver as default via 127.0.0.53 there is no dnssec validation. What is the reason for this behavior? I do not understand that.

Here is dig with the router on 192.168.178.1:

```
dig @192.168.178.1 www.cyberciti.biz +dnssec
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.178.1 www.cyberciti.biz +dnssec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11146
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cyberciti.biz.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.cyberciti.biz.      300     IN      A       104.22.10.214
www.cyberciti.biz.      300     IN      A       172.67.7.239
www.cyberciti.biz.      300     IN      A       104.22.11.214
www.cyberciti.biz.      300     IN      RRSIG   A 13 3 300 20210514214150 20210512194150 34505 cyberciti.biz. BX+7UsdHZbSxN8u4p1TLs4qU0WJ2WpIGwwKnbO/io2AbEvmYBBVnmorK WnGtLtp6ZCP0+wVn0gLRGwaeI+OAZQ==

;; Query time: 32 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Do Mai 13 22:41:50 CEST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 203
```

Here is dig with my `systemd-resolved` resolver:

```
root@dellxps13:/etc# dig @127.0.0.53 www.cyberciti.biz +dnssec

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.53 www.cyberciti.biz +dnssec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46609
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 65494
; OPT=5: 05 07 08 0a 0d 0e 0f (".......")
; OPT=6: 01 02 04 ("...")
; OPT=7: 01 (".")
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.cyberciti.biz.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.cyberciti.biz.      73      IN      A       172.67.7.239
www.cyberciti.biz.      73      IN      A       104.22.11.214
www.cyberciti.biz.      73      IN      A       104.22.10.214

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Do Mai 13 22:55:09 CEST 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

Here comes my /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=5.1.66.255 81.3.27.54 89.233.43.71
FallbackDNS=1.1.1.1
#Domains=
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=no
DNSSEC=allow-downgrade
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
Cache=no-negative
DNSStubListener=yes
ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

This is the output of `resolvectl status`:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=5.1.66.255 81.3.27.54 89.233.43.71
FallbackDNS=1.1.1.1
#Domains=
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=no
DNSSEC=allow-downgrade
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
Cache=no-negative
DNSStubListener=yes
ReadEtcHosts=yes
root@dellxps13:/etc# resolvectl status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: opportunistic       
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade     
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
  Current DNS Server: 5.1.66.255          
         DNS Servers: 5.1.66.255          
                      81.3.27.54          
                      89.233.43.71        
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1             
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 4 (enp63s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                      
DefaultRoute setting: yes                      
       LLMNR setting: yes                      
MulticastDNS setting: no                       
  DNSOverTLS setting: opportunistic            
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade          
    DNSSEC supported: no                       
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.1            
         DNS Servers: 192.168.178.1            
                      fd00::9a9b:cbff:fe92:c76d
          DNS Domain: ~.                       
                      fritz.box                

Link 2 (wlp2s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                      
DefaultRoute setting: yes                      
       LLMNR setting: yes                      
MulticastDNS setting: no                       
  DNSOverTLS setting: opportunistic            
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade          
    DNSSEC supported: yes                      
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.1            
         DNS Servers: 192.168.178.1            
                      fd00::9a9b:cbff:fe92:c76d
          DNS Domain: ~.                       
                      fritz.box
```

Is there anywhere a configuration file that I have to change, so that dnssec is turned on? Thank you very much for your help! Ralph T.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it appears your router does not set the "ad" flag while mine does. In both our cases, the local 127.0.0.53 provider never has the "ad" flag set, which is what indicates the 'authenticated data' bit I believe.

`flags: qr rd ra ad` from my router, `flags: qr rd ra` from the local system, both for the same query.